# Hot to create New folder batch file syntax?

Tags: batch-file, syntax

I would like to ask for an example of a syntax that will create a New Folder, using current date as name, containing 3 sub-folders inside.

Also I would like it to use a different time format from what the system uses as regional settings - current system time uses format `dd.mm.yyyy`

Example:

Main folder name: `mm.dd.yyyy`

Sub folders:

```
1. morning

2. day

3. night
```

Any suggestions? Is it possible, or would a javascript be a simpler solution?

Comment: Have you ever bothered to read the article [ask] or even the [tour]? You would know that such a question is off-topic here then, because StackOverflow is not a tutorial site, it is a resource for programmers to find answers to specific questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples on this site of how to get the date format in a standard, non localised format. Perhaps this method, using `WMIC` will do what you need:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC OS Get LocalDateTime') Do For %%B In (%%~nA
) Do Set "yyyyMMddhhmmss=%%B"
For %%A In ("morning" "day" "night"
) Do MD "%yyyyMMddhhmmss:~4,2%.%yyyyMMddhhmmss:~6,2%.%yyyyMMddhhmmss:~,4%\%%~A"
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need. I only need to put a space in the folder names now, but all in all this works perfectly!

Thank you very much! :)